# how to use getClass public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)?

Tags: java, android

I try to use `.getClass`method in `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` but Logcat gives me an error `PID: 6332
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference` .

My code:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
        menuSettings.setVisible(false);
        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setTitle("Bookmark");
    } else {
        menuSettings.setVisible(true);
        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbar.setTitle("");

    }
    return true;

}
```

and this:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_bookmark) {
        String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (!activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
            goToFragment(bookmarkFragment, false);
        }

    }
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This means that

```
findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
```

returns null. Means there is no such object/fragment.

Comment: but there must be this object/fragment

Comment: Have you checked this in debugger?

Comment: Then read first any book or tutorial about software development.